# How to parse JSON from stdin at Native Messaging host?

Tags: json, bash, stdin, jq, chrome-native-messaging

Utilizing the code at [How do I use a shell-script as Chrome Native Messaging host application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24764657/how-do-i-use-a-shell-script-as-chrome-native-messaging-host-application) as a template and given the file `file.json` which contains

```
{"text":"abc"}
```

following the code at [Iterate over json with jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48005870/iterate-over-json-with-jq/) and the [jq documentation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/)

```
$ cat file.json | jq --raw-output '.text'
```

outputs

```
abc
```

Am not certain how to incorporate the pattern at this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48006169/)

```
while read -r id name date; do
    echo "Do whatever with ${id} ${name} ${date}"
done< <(api-producing-json | jq --raw-output '.newList[] | "\(.id) \(.name) \(.create.date)"')
```

into the template at the former Answer for the purpose of capturing the single property `"text"` (`abc`) from the `JSON` within the loop using `jq` for the ability to pass that text to another system call then `printf` the message to client.

What we are trying to achieve is

```
json=$(<bash program> <captured JSON property>)
message='{"message": "'$json'"}'
```

where the `{"text":"abc"}` is sent to the Native Messaging host from client (Chromium app).

How to use `jq` within the code at the former [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24777120/) to get the `JSON` property as a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that file.json contains the JSON as indicated, I believe all you will need is:

```
json=$(jq '{message: .}' file.json)
```

If you then `echo "$json"`, the result will be:

```
{
  "message": {
    "text": "abc"
  }
}
```