# Using yq in for loop bash

Tags: bash, yq

I have a yaml array like below,

```
identitymappings:
- arn: "arn:aws:iam::12345567:role/AdmRole"
  group: "system:masters"
  user: "user1"
- arn: "arn:aws:iam::12345567:role/TestRole"
  group: "system:masters"
  user: "user2"
```

I am trying to parse this yaml in a bash script using for loop and yq.

```
 for identityMapping in $(yq read test.yaml "identitymappings[*]"); do
      roleArn=$identityMapping["arn"]
      group=$identityMapping.group
      user=$identityMapping.user
done
```

But I am not getting the expected results like not able to fetch the values of roleArn,group,user.
Please let me know how to fix this.

Comment: This is very closely related to [iterate over json with jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48005870/iterate-over-json-with-jq).

Answer (score 20):

The way I would do it is:

```sh
# load array into a bash array
# need to output each entry as a single line
readarray identityMappings < <(yq e -o=j -I=0 '.identitymappings[]' test.yml )

for identityMapping in "${identityMappings[@]}"; do
    # identity mapping is a yaml snippet representing a single entry
    roleArn=$(echo "$identityMapping" | yq e '.arn' -)
    echo "roleArn: $roleArn"
done
```

output:

```
roleArn: arn:aws:iam::12345567:role/AdmRole
roleArn: arn:aws:iam::12345567:role/TestRole
```

Disclaimer: I wrote yq

Comment: note that the latest `yq` now also has a '@tsv' operator (so you can do it the way @charles-duffy posted without needing jq).

Comment: The disclaimer though xD.

Comment: yq e .identitymappings[] file.yml

Answer (score 6):

I wasn't able to comment on Charles Duffy's proper answer, but this works for yq v4 without the use of jq...

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r roleArn group user _; do
  echo "Role:  $roleArn"
  echo "Group: $group"
  echo "User:  $user"
done < <(yq e '.identitymappings[] | [.arn, .group, .user] | @tsv' test.yaml)
```

Comment: Good to know; BTW, TSV values might be escaped (with `\t` `\\ ` `\n` etc...); you can unescape them with for example `printf -v roleArn %b "$roleArn"`

Answer (score 4):

There is an improvement of @Rad4's answer that worked for me.

You can neatly loop through using latest `yq` and `jq` via:

```
for im in $(yq eval -o=j test.yaml | jq -cr '.identitymappings[]'); do
      arn=$(echo $im | jq -r '.arn' -)
      group=$(echo $im | jq -r '.group' -)
      user=$(echo $im | jq -r '.user' -)
      echo $arn $group $user
done
```

This loops through valid online jsons, which makes `jq` still work inside the loop.

Answer (score 3):

1. Get `identitymappings` length
2. Using index to access element of `identitymappings`

```
array_length=`yq e ". identitymappings | length - 1" test.yaml`

if [ $array_length -le 0 ] ; then
  exit
fi

for element_index in `seq 0 $array_length`;do
    arn=`yq e ".identitymappings[$element_index]. arn" test.yml`
    group=`yq e ".identitymappings[$element_index]. group" test.yml`
    user=`yq e ".identitymappings[$element_index]. user" test.yml`
done
```

1. How to get length of array in yq?

   - https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/length

Comment: I find this approach the most straight forward. It allows to utilise yq for parsing data, instead of worrying about the outputs of yq and reading them in bash.

The only thing I would change is replace backticks with $()

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to read from jq or yq into bash is to use a [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) `while read` loop to handle line-oriented data; in the below, we use `@tsv` to generate line-oriented output:

```
while IFS=$'\t' read -r roleArn group user _; do
  echo "Role:  $roleArn"
  echo "Group: $group"
  echo "User:  $user"
done < <(yq -j read test.yaml \
         | jq -r '.identitymappings[] | [.arn, .group, .user] | @tsv')
```

Note that if you were using [the Python `yq`](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq/) rather than [the Go one](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), you could remove the `yq -j read` and just use `yq -r '...'` in place of `jq -r '...'`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @mike.f is a good one. However, it does not work on OSX machines, because `readarray` is not an available command.
You can read more about this [here](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/reading-output-into-array#common-pitfalls).

Here is the equivalent that would work on a mac:

```
# load array into a bash array
# need to output each entry as a single line
identitymappings=( $(yq e -o=j -I=0 '.identitymappings[]' test.yml ) )

for identityMapping in "${identityMappings[@]}"; do
    # identity mapping is a yaml snippet representing a single entry
    roleArn=$(echo "$identityMapping" | yq e '.arn' -)
    echo "roleArn: $roleArn"
done
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured out..

```
for identityMapping in $(yq read test.yaml -j "identitymappings[*]"); do
      echo $identityMapping
      roleArn= echo $identityMapping | jq -r '.arn'
      echo $roleArn
      group= echo $identityMapping | jq -r '.group'
      echo $group
      user= echo $identityMapping | jq -r '.user'
      echo $user
```

Comment: No. This isn't assigning values to `roleArn`, `group` or `user` at all. Your output isn't written from the `echo`s, it's written by the `jq` commands.

Comment: That's because `roleArn= echo $identityMapping | jq -r '.arn'` doesn't assign to `roleArn`, it's just setting `roleArn` as an environment variable with an empty value during the execution of `echo`.

Comment: ...see [How do I set a variable to the output of a command in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-do-i-set-a-variable-to-the-output-of-a-command-in-bash)