# how to use two variables in a for loop in shell script

Tags: shell

how to use two variables in a for loop in a shell script.

Below is the id and name of the projects got using jq operation.

```
Netbank734113 8a70803f8045722601804f62d54c5d9d
Netbank734112 8a70801c804568ae01804f625a923f8d
```

Have separated name and Id in different variables using the below commands

```
projectname=$(echo "$runIds" | awk '{print $1}')
projectId=$(echo "$runIds" | awk '{print $2}')

  echo "$projectname"
  echo "$projectId"

# response
# project-names
Netbank734113
Netbank734112

# there respective Ids
8a70803f8045722601804f62d54c5d9d
8a70801c804568ae01804f625a923f8d
```

I need a project-id for doing some operation. I'm using the below for-loop for it.

```
count=0
for i ${projectId}
 do

   count=`expr $count + 1`  
   echo "Project-ID: ${i} count: ${count}"
   echo " "  
   sleep 2
 done
```

I wanna use/print project names with their associated project ids in that for-loop during script execution, just to identify the name of the project script is working on.
Something like the below response

```
ProjectName: Netbank734113 Project-ID: 8a70803f8045722601804f62d54c5d9d 1
ProjectName: Netbank734112 Project-ID: 8a70801c804568ae01804f625a923f8d 2
```

I don't think nested for-loop will help in my case.

So, is there a way in shell script with which I can achieve the above use case?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48005870/iterate-over-json-with-jq ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of splitting the value into columns, use a `while-read` loop:

```sh
jq ... | while read -r name id; do
    echo "ProjectName: $name Project-ID: $id"
done
```

Or, if you're doing more than just echo-ing the output

```sh
while read -r name id; do
    echo "ProjectName: $name Project-ID: $id"
done < <(
    jq ...
)
```

Or, piping into awk would be a little shorter:

```sh
jq ... | awk '{print "ProjectName:", $1, "Project-ID:", $2}'
```

Or, just format the output in [jq](/questions/tagged/jq)

```sh
echo '
  [
      {"name": "Netbank734113", "id": "8a70803f8045722601804f62d54c5d9d"},
      {"name": "Netbank734112", "id": "8a70801c804568ae01804f625a923f8d"}
  ]
' | jq -r '.[] | "ProjectName: \(.name) Project-ID: \(.id)"'
```

```
ProjectName: Netbank734113 Project-ID: 8a70803f8045722601804f62d54c5d9d
ProjectName: Netbank734112 Project-ID: 8a70801c804568ae01804f625a923f8d
```